# How can I determine if a Guest responded "Yes" in Google Calendar Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Hi I'm trying to measure how many people responded yes to my events for Q1 on a spreadsheet. I'm using the Google Calendar API on a Google Sheet.

I see [Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/guest-status) has ways to check guest status but I don't understand how it would work. These events are 1 on 1 so there's always only 2 guests (me and the client). So If I see 2 "Yes" I know they attended. However if I could also see the guest's email/name that would be even better, but I know that's a lot to ask.

Here's my formula, thank you so much!

```
 function getEvents() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
     var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("mysheet")
     var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("1/1/2020 12:00 AM "), new Date("4/30/2020 11:59 PM"))

     for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++){

       var title = events[i].getTitle();
       var date = events[i].getStartTime();
       //doesn't work....var guests = events[i].getGuestStatus();
       var description = events[i].getDescription();

       Logger.log(title);



       ss.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(title)
       ss.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(date)
       //doesn't work....ss.getRange(i+2,3).setValue(guests)
       ss.getRange(i+2,4).setValue(description)

     }

    }
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. If you want each guest to show up in a new line you can use "; \n";. I very much appreciate your code.

Answer (score 1):

### To get the guest status you need to retrieve `events[i].getGuestList()`, loop through the guest list and retrieve for each guest `guests[j].getGuestStatus()`

Sample

```
...
var title = events[i].getTitle();
var date = events[i].getStartTime();
var guests = events[i].getGuestList();
var guestInfo = "";
for (var j = 0; j < guests.length; j++) {
  var guest = guests[j].getEmail();
  var status = guests[j].getGuestStatus();
  Logger.log(guest);
  guestInfo += guest+": " + status + ", ";
  }
Logger.log(guestInfo);
...
```